# Browser does not clear old Profile image ,Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, session, caching

I have updated the profile image successfully but during displaying it shows old.
I have check in uploaded folder that new image has been replaced.
Please check my code

```
<?php $filename=base_url().'profileimage/'.$this->session->userdata['user_details']['user_id'].'.jpg'; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $filename.'?='.filemtime($filename); ?>" class="rounded" alt="" width="150" height="150">
```

Comment: I guess that's the cached version of the image, try hard-reload or `ctrl+f5`

Comment: You are using session for $filename, that means you have to update your session's filename after uploading your image successfully to the folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is browser cache so you can call a get param after the image URL,
When each time the image is called the rand no will change so the browser can take the image as the new image to avoid cache after image replaced with the same name or you can change the image name instead of user id.

Remember this may take loading time every time you load the page so better change the image name once you replaced with the new image.

**image.jpg?randrom_no=123**

Refer the code

```
<?php $filename=base_url().'profileimage/'.$this->session->userdata['user_details']['user_id'].'.jpg'; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $filename.'?rand='.rand(1,2000); ?>" class="rounded" alt="" width="150" height="150">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way to show profile image.i hope it will work for you.

```
<img class="rounded" src="<?php
                        if ($_SESSION['userdata']['user_profile_image'] !== '' && file_exists(FCPATH . 'profileimage/' . $_SESSION['userdata']['user_profile_image'])) {
                            echo base_url() . 'profileimage' . $_SESSION['userdata']['filename'];
                        } else {
                            echo base_url() . 'dummyimage';
                        }
                        ?>" alt="" width="150" height="150">
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is not your code problem.This is your browser cache problem.You need to clear your browser cache. If you are using google chrome than refresh your page with pressing **ctrl + Shift + R**.